# Is tensorflow dataset 'prefetch' method add a dimension for my data? why?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is an example, this func is used to cut time sequence into windows:

```
def window_dataset(tensor, window_size, batch_size=32,
                   shuffle_buffer=1000):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)
    print(dataset.element_spec)

    dataset = dataset.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    print(dataset.element_spec)

    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + 1))
    print(dataset.element_spec)

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
    print(dataset.element_spec)

    dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))
    print(dataset.element_spec)

    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
    print(dataset.element_spec)

    return dataset
```

call && output:

```
list_a = np.random.random(184)
window_dataset(list_a, 30)
```

```
TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)
DatasetSpec(TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorShape([]))
TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)
TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)
(TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))
```

It seemed that the dataset have one more rank after prefetch, is it?
I didn't find any doc to describe this phenomenon, i will be appreciate if anybody could offer help.

============================================================
updated at 2021-03-25 12:28:16 UTC+0

I found this to be a little embarrassing misunderstanding, thanks to @ Lescurel for pointing this out. In fact, `prefetch` does not affect the dimension, and `batch` will add a dimension. The modification example is as follows:

```
def window_dataset(tensor, window_size, batch_size=32,
                   shuffle_buffer=1000):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)
    print(dataset.element_spec)
    dataset = dataset.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    print(dataset.element_spec)
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + 1))
    print(dataset.element_spec)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
    print(dataset.element_spec)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))
    print(dataset.element_spec)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    print(dataset.element_spec)
    
    
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
    print(dataset.element_spec)
    return dataset
```

call && output:

```
list_a = np.random.random(184)
window_dataset(list_a, 30)
```

```
TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)
DatasetSpec(TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorShape([]))
TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)
TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)
(TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))
# after batch
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))
# after prefetch
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))
```

It is clear now.

Comment: `prefetch` does not, but `batch` does. Did you overlook that you were calling `batch`?

Comment: @Lescurel Thanks for helping! That's true. Maybe i should call methods in different lines before understanding well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prefetch` allows later elements to be prepared while the current element is being processed. This often improves latency and throughput at the cost of using additional memory to store prefetched elements.

Where as `batch` is combines consecutive elements of dataset into batches based on `batch_size`.

It has no concept of examples vs. batches. `examples.prefetch(2)` will prefetch `two elements (2 examples)`, while `examples.batch(20).prefetch(2)` will prefetch `2 elements (2 batches, of 20 examples each)`.

For more details you can refer [methods](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#methods_2) of tf.data.Dataset.